# How to get bitcoin address from a public key with bitcoinjs

Tags: javascript, bitcoin

Found an article explaining how to generate bitcoin address from a public key:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses

But wondering if this procedure is already implemented in [bitcoinjs](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib) or any other JS library. So I don't need to perform all the 8 steps from the guide manually

Comment: Bitcoin address is just a SHA256 hash of the public key, any library that has a SHA256 function will get you an address from a public key.

Comment: @Adam It's a bit more than that, it's a SHA256 hash, which is then RIPEMD160 hashed and then encoded in Base58 with a checksum (which comes from a double SHA256 of the RIPEMD160 hash).

Comment: @Adam but this guide I mentioned states that there are whole 8 steps to get the address. That's why I'm asking. Will try to do just SHA256. Thank you!

Comment: @DmitryTaipov - listen to paulpro, my memory was wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that library can do it.

```
const bitcoinjs = require( 'bitcoinjs-lib' );

const pubkey = Buffer.from( '0250863ad64a87ae8a2fe83c1af1a8403cb53f53e486d8511dad8a04887e5b2352', 'hex' );
const { address } = bitcoinjs.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey });
console.log( address ); // 1PMycacnJaSqwwJqjawXBErnLsZ7RkXUAs
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! That's exactly what I needed. Maybe that's a separate question but I only got a 64 byte long (uncompressed) public key like this: `08d6770d8219923fe25a4d6aeb2c171253d5de3bc225f09dbfb2cb93ed837be1a80fdd3af5046b8f1f5412e5b321dcc3c25be9f4dd285250421ea55071794277`. And `bitcoinjs.payments.p2pkh()` takes only 32 byte key. How can 64 bytes key be converted to 32 bytes one? Or maybe there is another function in bitcoinjs which takes the longer keys?

Comment: @DmitryTaipov [See this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/48863/9340). The buffer should be either `33` or `65` bytes. If I prepend a `04` in front of your public key I get an address `17WseNiLB8Kbp4L73pL3FDsfyYN86c82Em`, but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for (The same public key results in two different addresses if it's in the compressed format vs the uncompressed format).

Comment: taking the left half of 64 bytes key and adding `03` to the beginning worked for me. Appreciate your help!